# knockout is not working under document.ready

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i am working on knockout and having issues. below is my .js code and  `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` is all the way down under document.ready and its not working at all. it only works when i add

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

in side method  $('#dtTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (). Please suggest what is the issue if i place my code inside data table row click, once i click on 2nd time other row or same row error comes "we can not define binding multiple times".
Please tell me issue in code and 2nd where should i put apply bindings

```
/// <reference path="knockout-3.1.0.debug.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {     

    var viewModel = new function () {
        this.firstname = ko.observable();
        this.lastname = ko.observable();

    };


    $('#dTable').dataTable({
            "scrollY": 300,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "jQueryUI": true        
     });   

    var selectedRow;

    $('#dTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        selectedRow = $(this).closest('tr');

        viewModel.firstname = selectedRow.context.cells(0).innerHTML;
        viewModel.lastname = selectedRow.context.cells(1).innerHTML;        

    });  


    $('#btnSaveChanges').click(function () {      

        var saveRequest = new Object();

        saveRequest.FirstName = viewModel.firstname;
        saveRequest.LastName = viewModel.lastname; 


        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Person/GetPerson',
            data: JSON.stringify(saveRequest),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == true) {

                    alert("Division saved successfully!");

                    if ($("#clickedButton").val() == "Add") {
                        AddNewRowToDataTable(saveRequest);
                    }
                    else {
                        UpdateRowToDataTable();
                    }

                }
                else {
                    alert("did not save!");
                }
            }
        });


    });

    var t = $('#dTable').DataTable();

    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {

        $("#clickedButton").val("Add");

        viewModel.firstname = "";
        viewModel.lastname = "";

    });

    function AddNewRowToDataTable(saveRequest) {
        t.row.add([
           saveRequest.FirstName,
           saveRequest.LastName,

        ]).draw();
    }

    function UpdateRowToDataTable() {
        selectedRow.context.cells(0).innerHTML = viewModel.firstname; 
        selectedRow.context.cells(1).innerHTML = viewModel.lastname; 

    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

Thanks and waiting for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewModel.firstname` and `viewModel.lastnames` are observables. You assign values to them like this...

```
viewModel.firstname(selectedRow.context.cells(0).innerHTML);
viewModel.lastname(selectedRow.context.cells(1).innerHTML);
```

When you use an assignment statement, you're essentially overwriting the observable with something else. The view is still binding to the observables the first time `ko.applyBindings()` was run, that's why the value doesn't change until you reapply the bindings again (which you should not have to do).

Once those assignments are fixed, there will be a problem with this code...

```
saveRequest.FirstName = viewModel.firstname;
saveRequest.LastName = viewModel.lastname;
```

If `firstname` and `lastname` are observables, you need to access their values by invoking them...

```
saveRequest.FirstName = viewModel.firstname();
saveRequest.LastName = viewModel.lastname();
```